# Is it possible to write a QT C++ project on an Intel machine that produces a binary for Solaris SPARC?

Tags: c++, solaris, cross-compiling, intel, sparc

Is it possible to write a C++ application on Intel that produces an executable binary for Solaris SPARC architecture using QT?

I have downloaded QT 4.7.4 and opened some of the demo projects like "Address Book Example" and performed a build / execute on my Mac. It appears to run without problem, but when I try to change the target to something other than "Desktop QT 4.8.1" there are no options to choose a SPARC target machine.

Am I completely out of line thinking I can cross compile from intel to sparc with QT?

Comment: The most natural "Intel" platform would be Solarix/x86, not MacOSX.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can Cross Compile. There are so many resources in google http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~milom/cross-compile.html